# {Newbie} Removing ActionBar Title

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to remove title from the ActionBar. Here is what I did:

I created a HelloWorld app using the [first tutorial here](http://developer.android.com). Then I tried to remove the title from ActionBar by removing *showTitle* flag from *displayOptions* attribute. The title was not removed. But when I also set `android:label=" "`, the title was removed but also the name of the application from the application Launcher.

How do I remove just the title from the ActionBar?

#### styles.xml

```
<resources>

   <!--
       Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
       by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
   -->
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <!--
           Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
           res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
           backward-compatibility can go here.
       -->
   </style>

   <!-- Application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level
            can go here. -->
   </style>

   <style name="ActionBarNoTitle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
       <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
   </style>

   <style name="NoTitleActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarNoTitle</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.test.notitle"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.test.notitle.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/NoTitleActivityTheme" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to call `getActionBar()` in the activity, and then call the `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean showTitle)` on it or the `setTitle(CharSequence title)` where you can pass an empty String.
Checkout the [ActionBar developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) for more details.

Untested code:

```
// Put this at the appropriate location. The `onCreate()` might be a good candidate.
final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("");                      // Use this
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // OR this
```

Comment: I tried that too before posting my query. But that solution does not give the desired output. When the app is launched the title appears for a few seconds in the ActionBar and then it is removed. That is not what I am looking for.